# Gecko:Login to website

Tags: vb.net, gecko

I am new to web browser control geckoFx. I want to login to a webpage using it. So how can i do it in vb.net

I tried navigating to the webpage using navigate method.

```
InitializeComponent()
Xpcom.Initialize("D:\xulrunner")
myBrowser = New GeckoWebBrowser()
myBrowser.Parent = Me
myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
myBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com")
```

But how can i login to website?
I tried searching for few examples of using gecko.But i didn't get. So where i can get examples related to using gecko?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to do this. After you have navigate to the page and it has finished loading:

1. execute some javascript to fill in the fields and click the submit button.

[C# javascript execute examples](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/src/ecc807f364a8d23bae9dd9908b35ebbada5aa279/GeckofxUnitTests/GeckoWebBrowserTests.cs?at=default)

1. use C# (or vb.net) to get the required DOM fields, modify them with the required values, then get the DOM submit button and call the click api.

[Examples of GetElementById](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/src/ecc807f364a8d23bae9dd9908b35ebbada5aa279/GeckofxUnitTests/GeckoDocumentTests.cs?at=default)

[GeckoInputElement class that has a click method](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/src/ecc807f364a8d23bae9dd9908b35ebbada5aa279/Geckofx-Core/DOM/Html/HTMLInputElement.cs?at=default)

Comment: In all of the above examples no explanation or working example is given. Do gecko has any documentation with real time examples and samples?